# on FreeBSD, how to exit from Gnome Session to Pure terminal mode

Tags: gnome, freebsd

on FreeBSD, how to exit from Gnome Session to Pure terminal mode.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Ctrl+Alt+F2` key combination to go to text terminal, use `Ctrl+Alt+F9` to come back to Gnome or whatever you are running on top of X.

If you want to totally disable `X11` open `/etc/ttys` file, find the line that says:

```
ttyv8   "/usr/X11R6/bin/xdm -nodaemon"  xterm   off secure
```

comment it out, save the file and reboot.

Comment: Thank you. but not what I really want..I want to switch to pure terminal mode.

Comment: Updated my answer to disable X.